# Are there any Tools to Automate Migration from a Website to Amazon Webstore?

Tags: automation, migration, amazonsellercentral, webstore

we have a current website which shows the product, shopping cart and the whole shebang. and we're trying to migrate to Amazon web store, not the Cloud computing architecture type but the basic html web store method.

And based on the tools that i see is available on amazon web store, there seems to be a lot of html editing, excel file editing, etc.

i can see some of the process there which might get automated via perl scripting etc, but it still leaves a lot of work to be done.

So i was wondering if there's anybody else who has done this before and know of a better way to automate or setup a process so any future work can be hugely reduced down to as much automation as possible.

thanks!!

### Edit

In case somebody is as lost as i am i was able to [find some links on best practices](http://jon.redduckllc.com/2009/02/working-with-amazon-webstore-platform.html), and found out that there's actually a Amazon seller desktop and AMTU tool which can use xml or soap to handle some automation on the inventory management part.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon offers API for automated integration (although not all Webstore features are supported through these APIs).
The Marketplace Web Services API (mws.amazon.com) is well documented, and example client libraries are provided for Java, C# and PHP. For feed and report formats, you should refer to Seller Central Help pages for all formats, or to http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/tutorials/SOA-GuideToXML.pdf for more detailed documentation about XML formats.

For a higher level picture, www.amazonservices.com is a good start.